# Vue-router: Using component method within the router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My first Vue project and I want to run a loading effect on every router call.
I made a `Loading` component:

```
<template>
    <b-loading :is-full-page="isFullPage" :active.sync="isLoading" :can-cancel="true"></b-loading>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                isFullPage: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            openLoading() {
                this.isLoading = true
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false
                }, 10 * 1000)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I wanted to place inside the router like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.name) {
        Loading.openLoading()
    }
    next()
}
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: "_components_includes_Loading__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default.openLoading is not a function"

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuex is a good point. But for simplicity you can watch `$route` in your component, and show your loader when the `$route` changed, like this:

```js
...
watch: {
  '$route'() {
     this.openLoading()
   },
},
...
```

I think it's fast and short solution.

Comment: I placed watch in the component, but nothing happened

Comment: Does this watch method invoke? Can you put `console.log()` in it?

Comment: You component should alway be render in DOM (don't apply `v-if`) on it.

Comment: I replaced the component to the main componed and now it works 'til infinity. How can I watch if in the background everything is loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by __everything is loaded__? When does this event happen?

Comment: For example one of the page is a list of users where I get the information with axios. And everything is loaded there when axios get's the info and Buefy renders it

Comment: I tried the 'mounted()' function but it doesn't work

Comment: @Feralheart, what about EventBus solution?

Comment: This is my first Vue project and I didn't heard about it yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access a component method inside a navigation guard (`beforeEach`) i would suggest using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is a vue plugin for data management and then making `isLoading` a global variable so before each route navigation you would do the same ...  here is how you can do it :

Of course you need to install `Vuex` first with `npm i vuex` ... after that :

**on your main file where you are initializing your Vue instance** :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isLoading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    openLoading(state) {
      state.isLoading = true
      setTimeout(() => {
        state.isLoading = false
      }, 10000)
    },
  },
})
// if your router is on a separated file just export the store and import it there
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      // ...
    },
  ],
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name) {
    store.commit('openLoading')
  }
  next()
})

new Vue({
   /// ....
   router,
   store,
})
```

**In your component:**

```html
<b-loading :is-full-page="isFullPage" :active.sync="$store.state.isLoading" :can-cancel="true"></b-loading>
```

Comment: Using Vuex is a good point. But you answer has an error in this line `:active.sync="$store.state.isLoading"`. You will get Vuex warn because you can't mutate store directly, is suggest you to rewrite it using `getter` and `setter`.

Comment: Hi thanks but im not mutating the value there its just bidden ( not ´v-model´) and yes using a getter is better ofc .... Your solution is much better i guess you just need to include the condition that he is implemeting

Comment: Potentially, he is modifying it directly in component, because he added `.sync` modifier, which allows props changing.